# iPhone Table View: How to access text field of custom TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've set up a UITableView with several custom UITableViewCell's that have some UITextField's and UISwitch's (based on Settings.app). My question is, when a user clicks the Save button in the navigation bar, what's the beat way to access these text fields and switch controls to save their values?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My suggestion is to not use custom `UITableViewCell`s.  I used to do it your way, but there's a much better way.  Use the `accessoryView` property of the `UITableViewCell`, which you can assign an arbitrary view to, such as a `UITextField` or `UISwitch`.  It shows up exactly as it would in the Settings application.

Then, when you need to access it, just use

```
NSString *text = ((UITextField *)cell.accessoryView).text;
```

However, you must be careful about setting up cells and accessing their values.  If any cell goes offscreen, it will be removed and you will not be able to access the text field.  What you want to do when setting up your cell is:

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;  //Make sure any old accessory view isn't there.
if (/*cell needs text field*/) {
    UITextField *textField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    textField.text = savedValue;
    cell.accessoryView = textField;
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

...

- (void) textChanged:(UITextField *)source {
    self.savedValue = source.text;
}
```

Comment: What if I have more than one cell with a text field (like the add contact view on the contacts app)? Should I add a different method for each of the views?

Comment: Found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572377/iphone-how-to-read-the-data-in-uitableview/3572595#3572595 that you can change the tags for textfields, so I can have one method and switch on it.

Comment: I use UIControlEventEditingDidEnd. UIControlEventValueChanged doesn't seem to get called :?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't follow Ed's suggestion, you are probably best retaining your text view in the custom cell and adding a property to access the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have your custom cells keep a reference to your higher-level view controller and send it notifications when the user updates values in them. Basically, copy the delegate pattern used by many library objects in UIKit.