# iPhone how to read the data in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am working on a iPhone application it allows users to edit the data shown in the table view.
In this task I use custom `UITableViewCell` which consist of `UILabel` and `UITextField`.
After editing finish how can I read the values in UITextField of all rows ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to store the data in dictionary or an object in the delegate method didEndEditing of textfield.
First of all In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method set the tag of UITextfield object similar to indexpath.row

Hope the below sample code helps you

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case 0:
            objAboutYouClass.name=textField.text;           
            break;
        case 1:
            objAboutYouClass.email=textField.text;          
            break;
        case 2:
            objAboutYouClass.workRole=textField.text;           
            break;
        case 3:
            objAboutYouClass.area=textField.text;           
            break;
        case 4:
            objAboutYouClass.managersName=textField.text;           
            break;
        case 5:
            objAboutYouClass.securityQuestion=textField.text;           
            break;
        case 6:
            objAboutYouClass.answer=textField.text;         
            break;

        default:            
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the best approach i suppes. I have used class you can also use dictionary to store the content.

hAPPY cODING.....